# Nginx yum update checksum error on CentOS5 for CentOS6 package

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, yum

I'm getting checksum error when doing Yum update due to Yum looking for Nginx package from CentOS 6 repo (I'm using Centos 5.6).

Below is the error:
    http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/x86_64/repodata/a017491800bf2f9c0d3d043d30ca1e065ff89212b35159c0fa201fd9c02f77f3-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
    Trying other mirror.

Is there a way to uninstall Nginx from Yum manually?

Comment: nginx provided a repo for CentOS 5; why did you not use it?

Answer (score 3):

Installing packages from a CentOS 6 repo on CentOS 5 is ill-advised and should be avoided. Please just upgrade to CentOS 6 completely if you want this. Alternatively, manually grab the source rpm and rebuild it on CentOS 5.

As to why this fails: the newer createrepo for CentOS 6 uses a different algorithm for checksums than the one used by yum in CentOS 5 (sha256 vs sha1 iirc), so your yum has no way of verifying the repository contents.

Comment: Unfortunately CentOS upgrade is not really stable according to Red Hat website so they advise re-install. I don't really want to do that as it would be a lot of hassles with multiple configurations done on the site. I would rather uninstall Nginx manually as it's not used at the moment. Is there a way to uninstall Nginx in this case?

Comment: `yum remove nginx` will remove it and everything that depends on it. You will also need to remove the nginx repository from your yum config.

Comment: I still get the same checksum error as per my initial post above when I do yum remove nginx

Comment: That's because you didn't do the second thing I said :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below command

```
   yum clean all
```

and then a

```
   yum update
```

or a

```
   yum upgrade
```

Comment: While good advise in general, this won't help in this case as the repository and yum are fundamentally incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message.  In my case, the problem was that the repository server indexed its RPMs using the *sha256* checksum algorithm while the `yum` client software only knew about plain *sha* checksums.

My solution:

1. Install `python-hashlib` *(docs for Python [2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) / [3](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/hashlib.html))*.
2. Remove the 2 files `/usr/lib/python*/site-packages/yum/{repos,misc}.pyc`
3. Patch the file `/usr/lib/python*/site-packages/yum/repos.py` by replacing:

   ```
       elif sumtype == 'sha':
           import sha
           sum = sha.new()
       else:
           raise Errors.RepoError, 'Error Checksumming file, wrong \                                                                                                                      
                                    checksum type %s' % sumtype
   ```

   ... with:

   ```
       elif sumtype == 'sha':
           import sha
           sum = sha.new()
       else:
           import hashlib
           if "algorithms" in hashlib.__dict__ and sumtype in hashlib.algorithms:
               sum = hashlib.new(sumtype)
           elif sumtype in hashlib.__dict__:
               sum = hashlib.__dict__[sumtype]()
           else:
               raise Errors.RepoError, 'Error Checksumming file, wrong \                                                                                                                      
                                        checksum type %s' % sumtype
   ```
4. Patch the file `/usr/lib/python*/site-packages/yum/misc.py` by replacing:

   ```
   else:
       raise MiscError, 'Error Checksumming file, bad checksum type %s' % sumtype
   ```

   ... with:

   ```
   else:
       import hashlib
       if "algorithms" in hashlib.__dict__ and sumtype in hashlib.algorithms:
           sum = hashlib.new(sumtype)
       elif sumtype in hashlib.__dict__:
           sum = hashlib.__dict__[sumtype]()
       else:
           raise MiscError, 'Error Checksumming file, bad checksum type %s' % sumtype
   ```

`yum` should now understand and handle the *sha256* checksums distributed by the repository server, so you should be able to run your command again without this issue showing up.

The new code will attempt to use `hashlib` when the `yum` client does not already recognize the checksum.  It should be flexible enough to handle the future addition of hashes to `hashlib` and the repository indexer itself without further modification of the `yum` client.